# how to update package-lock.json file in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

The security part of GateLab gives me a message to update the ‍‍`package-lock.json` file.
The text of the message is as follows :

‍Known security vulnerabilities detected

Dependency
object-path
Version
< `0.11.5`
Upgrade to
~> `0.11.5`
Defined in
`package-lock.json`
Vulnerabilities
CVE-2020-15256 High severity

Dependency
elliptic
Version
< `6.5.4`
Upgrade to
~> `6.5.4`
Defined in
package-lock.json
Vulnerabilities
CVE-2020-28498 Moderate severity

Dependency
is-svg
Version

= `2.1.0` < `4.2.2`
Upgrade to
~> `4.2.2`

Defined in
`package-lock.json`
Vulnerabilities
CVE-2021-28092 Moderate severity

Dependency
ssri
Version

= `5.2.2` < `8.0.1`
Upgrade to
~> `8.0.1`

Defined in
`package-lock.json`
Vulnerabilities
CVE-2021-27290 Moderate severity

but packages will not be updated when I update npm with `npm update`

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP since `npm` is a dependency manager for JavaScript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not Laravel related as has been mentioned, you can use a packaged called [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to check for updates to your `package.json`

It is installed like this

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

And you can use it by running

```
ncu
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**

Run `npm outdated` to check all the outdated packages. You will see the wanted version in the results.

Run `npm update` to update to the `wanted` version.

**2**

If that doesn't work, try to install them manually.

`npm install object-path@~0.11.5`

**3 **CAUTION****

You can also update all dependencies to the latest versions by

`npx npm-check-updates -u`

**YOU MAY ENCOUNTER COMPATIBILITY PROBLEM AFTER BLINDLY UPDATING, YOUR PROJECT MAY EXPLODE.**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```